# how to set text property assigned to the control created dynamically usiong reflection?-C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

how to set text property  assigned to the control created dynamically usiong reflection?

```
Type type = Type.GetType(strFullName);

    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    ctrlTemp = (Control)instance;

    ctrlTemp.ID = "Hello";
    ctrlTemp.Text???
    Panel1.Controls.Add(ctrlTemp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PropertyInfo.SetValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) : Sets the value of the property with optional index values for index properties.

```
PropertyInfo piInstance = 
            typeof(Example).GetProperty("InstanceProperty");
        piInstance.SetValue(exam, 37, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ctrlTemp.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
{
    TextBox textbox = (TextBox)ctrlTemp;
    ctrlTemp.Text = "Your text";
}
```